# Ubuntu Apache Using Wrong VHosts For Sites

Tags: apache, vhosts, certbot

I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4, and have vhost configured, with all .conf files located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and all enabled sites at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` using `a2ensite` for each site conf. I have 000-default.conf disabled, and I'm using certbot, along with the latest of apache and PHP 7.2.x.

Two of my sites have an issue with the vhost configuration. The sites are:

```
Site 1: clients.site1.com.conf
Site 2: clients.site2.com.conf
Site 3: site3.com.conf (Mention later)
```

If I go to `clients.site1.com` in the browser, it loads fine.

If I go to `clients.site2.com` in the browser, the url shows `clients.site2.com` loaded, but it is actually loading `clients.site1.com` content from `/var/www/clients.site1.com/public_html`.

I've checked `clients.site1.com.conf`, and have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@clients.site1.com
    ServerName clients.site1.com
    ServerAlias clients.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/clients.site1.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =clients.site1.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've checked `clients.site2.com.conf`, and have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@clients.site2.com
    ServerName clients.site2.com
    ServerAlias clients.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/clients.site2.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =clients.site2.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have played around with the file name of the conf files thinking that having two conf files with `clients.` had an issue with the wildcard matching. So I tried removing the dot `.`, and even tried replacing it with a hyphen `-`. Still the same result.

The last test I did was I disabled `clients.site1.com.conf`. When I did that and then proceeded with loading `clients.site2.com` in my browser, the next site in order of the conf files (Site 3 above to serve as an example) is what loads.

**UPDATE:**

I ran `apache2ctl -S` and got the following:

```
root@ip-111-111-111-111:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443 is a NameVirtualHost

 default server clients.site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/clients.site1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
 port 443 namevhost clients.site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/clients.site1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias clients.site1.com
 port 443 namevhost site3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site3.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.site3.com
 port 443 namevhost aaaaa.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/aaaaa.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.aaaaa.com
 port 443 namevhost bbbbb.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bbbbb.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.bbbbb.com
 port 443 namevhost ccccc.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ccccc.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.ccccc.com
 port 443 namevhost ddddd.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ddddd.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.ddddd.com
 port 443 namevhost eeeee.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eeeee.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.eeeee.com
 port 443 namevhost ip-111-111-111-111.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/fffff.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.fffff.com
 port 443 namevhost ggggg.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ggggg.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.ggggg.com
 port 443 namevhost site2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         alias www.site2.com
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
 default server ip-111-111-111-111.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost ip-111-111-111-111.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost clients.site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/clients.site1.com.conf:1)
         alias clients.site1.com
 port 80 namevhost clients.site2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/clients.site2.com.conf:1)
         alias clients.site2.com
 port 80 namevhost site3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site3.com.conf:1)
         alias www.site3.com
 port 80 namevhost aaaaa.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/aaaaa.com.conf:1)
         alias www.aaaaa.com
 port 80 namevhost bbbbb.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bbbbb.com.conf:1)
         alias www.bbbbb.com
 port 80 namevhost ccccc.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ccccc.com.conf:1)
         alias www.ccccc.com
 port 80 namevhost ddddd.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ddddd.com.conf:1)
         alias www.ddddd.com
 port 80 namevhost eeeee.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eeeee.com.conf:1)
         alias www.eeeee.com
 port 80 namevhost ip-111-111-111-111.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/fffff.com.conf:1)
         alias www.fffff.com
 port 80 namevhost ggggg.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ggggg.com.conf:1)
         alias www.ggggg.com
 port 80 namevhost site2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.com.conf:1)
         alias www.site2.com

ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
root@ip-111-111-111-111:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

Comment: we need to see `:443` VirtualHosts also.

Comment: I updated the solution to show 80 and 443 vhosts.

Comment: My post is downvoted?????????? This is why people are using SO less and less. What is wrong with my post? Why downvote when I've done my research, I could not find any solution to my problem, and I properly detailed what I've tried in an articulate manner.

Comment: It might be lets encrypt...can you add the clients.site1.com-le-ssl.conf file?

Comment: Your post fine, it is just borderline off topic here, maybe is better suited for ServerFault. Anyway, seems like thee is no :443 VirtualHost defined for clients.site2.com, which explains the behavior.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include let's encrypt, which might be what is causing the trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your response Dusan. I had found a lot of posts here at SO having to do with virtual host and apache. This is the reason I posted here. I'll post similar questions at serverfault from now on.

Kate, thank you for your response. I'm going to try that now.

Comment: Be sure to a2dissite to clean the slate, or apache will get confused.  You also might want to get to the two non-secure sites up and running first, then do the let's encrypt step to help debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to help with debugging:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

This will show you the vhost configuration that Apache believes you have.  it is important to `a2dissite` a configuration file before renaming it, etc.

> I have 000-default.conf disabled

You are better off keeping this enabled and creating a default file that is loaded when Apache doesn't know where to go.  It can be a very simple file that just says "error", but then you will be aware when Apache believes it has nowhere to go. Plus it is better security to have a honey pot for all requests coming in that aren't legitimate.  Lastly, I have this vague memory of discovering that it might actually pick one of the vhosts randomly if the 000-default is not set, but not sure, but it would explain the site 3 behavior.

Lastly, you have both `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` set to the same URL.  This is not necessary and while I don't think it is the problem, better to take it out of the mix.

Otherwise I do not see any problems with your vhosts files and should work.

**Update**

You are redirecting to the https URL.  So what is dictating Apache is the -le-ssl.com.conf file.  I have similarly fought this with Let's Encrypt.  Here are my procedures for making both Apache and Let's Encrypt happy:

- create the one configuration (website.com.conf) for the non-secure port 80
- `a2ensite website.com.conf`
- `apache2ctl graceful` (so Apache knows of the non-secure URL)
- `letsencrypt --apache -d website.com` (this will generate the entire -le-ssl file)
- `apache2ctl graceful`

Comment: I updated the solution to show the output from `apache2ctl -S`

Comment: I also enabled 000-default.conf

Comment: Katie, do you mean to literally make website.com.conf, or for me to recreate site2.com.conf again, and then execute the commands listed?

Comment: The cleanest thing you can do is start fresh.  a2dissite all of them, then slowly a2ensite each non-secure file and see if that works properly, then run the lets encrypt, which will then use the properly configured non-secure configuration files.  This is what has worked for me, and it feels like walking on eggshells with the two tools (apache and lets encrypt)

Comment: (and judiciously use renaming files to keep them safe)

Comment: :) I agree about walking on eggshells with apache and LE. I was able to add another vhost site a few weeks ago as well as get a cert issued for it. But it was very painful. I find that LE is very easy to use when everything is set up from a fresh OS install. Adding another site and cert after everything else is already configured is daunting.

I have 12 sites on this server, so doing what you suggested will take me more time than I have at the moment... I'm at the office right now! I'll do this later this evening and reply back.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Good luck! Yup, that is why I have set up the above procedures everytime I launch a live site, it seems to be the only way through...you may also want to delete the certificates at the same time, just to really clean it up and start over.  If you are live, it adds to the stress, then you have to step more carefully, but that is what I have done, painful as it is...

Comment: One last thought, before cleaning house, take a careful look at the le-ssl configurations, you still might find something simple.

Comment: I've not forgotten about this post. I have two tasks I need to complete this evening and through tomorrow. I'll try the steps you provided by Tuesday.

Comment: I tried the steps you mentioned above, and actually remade the 80 conf files for each site from scratch. Then got tho the 3rd bullet for the very first site in the list, and it says with the following error:
`Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log 
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache 
Obtaining a new certificate 
Performing the following challenges: 
Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA.`

Comment: Painful Katie!!! Painful! So from what I read, there is an issue with certbot at the moment using Apache and NGINX. But I did what you said to do, except I did everything in a batch. End the end, I did everything except for the letsencrypt command you provided. Instead, I had to run the following:

`sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache --pre-hook "service apache2 stop" --post-hook "service apache2 start"`

Everything appears to be running great now. But I did have 2 or 3 attempts before getting everything right. Thank you very much for the amazing instructions!

Comment: I feel your pain!  It will be nice when these apps starting playing nice.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: Hi Katie, after all the work done in January to get everything working, my server had issues again. I'm not sure what caused the problem, but I think it had to do with the cron I had set up to renew letsencrypt. I finished redoing all sites one by one just like you advised back in January, and everything is back to normal again. But I wanted to ask you, what do you run in cron to renew letsencrypt for all sites?

Comment: Hi Pegues!   Sorry I can't help, I hadn't gotten around to setting up a cron, as I always log in and update linux and do some housekeeping on all my servers each week, so I just run a quick letsencrypt renew directly.

Comment: No problem. I'll figure out a good cron job to run. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

In case it can help somebody : I had the exact same problem.

Several websites configured in Apache. They were working correctly.

I moved them to a new server. I don't know why (maybe a difference in the default Apache conf) but they started to behave like explained in the question, like "pointing" to a default site.

The reason was that I didn't have a ServerAlias line forwarding the "non www" name of the site to the "www prefixed" name.

I was used to typing "mydomainname.com" instead of "www.mydomainname.com" because I have a line in my DNS config that forwards the requests to www.xxxx if www is missing.

So, Apache was not finding the ServerName, and trying to pass the request to the default site.

But, because I has deleted the content of the 000-default.conf file, the request was passed to the first working website.

So make sure you have :

- A working 000-default.conf file
- A ServerAlias for your www prefixed site like

  ServerAlias www.yourdomainname.com